# c++ : how to write text to a file infinitely (inside infinite loop)?

Tags: c++, linux

I need to write into a file (.txt) infinitely every 5 seconds
this's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream file("inc.txt");

    while(true)
    {
        file << "Whatever\n" ;
        sleep(5);
    }
}
```

When I run the program nothing happen to the .txt file!

Comment: manual `flush` may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already write infinitely inside the file. but with buffering, you don't see the result in file, using `flush` solves that:

```
while (true)
{
    file << "Whatever\n";
    file.flush(); // Force the write into the file.
    sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: `file << "Whatever" << std::endl` will also flush the buffer.

Comment: @AndyG: As I said in my answer, 15 minutes ago!

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: I posted this comment before I saw yours. Then I saw yours (and upvoted it) 15 minutes ago!

Answer (score 3):

File output is *buffered* to save your hard disk from excessive wear. It is going to take a long time, at 1.8 bytes per second, to hit the buffer limit and see observable results.

If you wish to see every line written immediately, you can request a buffer flush manually:

```
file << "Whatever\n" << flush;
```

Or, equivalently:

```
file << "Whatever" << endl;
```

Comment: i did write "\n" it's the same as endl, isn't ?

Comment: @AmerAlahmar: No. As I wrote in my answer, `<< endl` is the same as `<< '\n' << flush`.